# Is there any winJS plugin for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, microsoft-metro, winjs

I like the easy way to use jQuery and would prever to use it also in metro style apps. I would like to have a plugin/wrapper/monkey-patch, that uses the winJS-Functions in jQuery. For example I'am using the following plugin to avoid MSPointer-Problems:

```
$.fn.msMousedown = function(handler) {
    var eventType = 'mousedown touchstart';
        if (window.navigator.msPointerEnabled)
          eventType = 'MSPointerDown';
    this.bind(eventType,handler);
})( jQuery );
```

Is there any project that I can use that does this handling for me? Maybe a jQuery-Plugin, that allows to just use jQuery in Windows 8-Projects?

In my opinion winJS is to complicated and would be much easier if it uses the simple jQuery-syntax. So I'am searching for an alternative to winJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [my jqToDo sample](https://github.com/gzortch/jqToDo). It has a reusable wrapper script that makes WinJS controls look like jQueryUI widgets.

Comment: Haven't tried it, to be honest, but I'd be shocked if the app store disallowed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery directly in a WinRT project.  You need to add the jQuery files directly to your project (do not reference from CDN) since files need to be available even when offline.  It also provides a correct security context.  I did a very short, very simple example video here... http://slickthought.net/post/2012/08/01/Windows-8-and-HTML-Part-2-3rd-Party-Frameworks.aspx

Includes a quick example using both jQuery and jsRender.

You can also mix-and-match --- the two frameworks are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: I know that i can use jQuery inside my WinRT projects. But I dislike the mix of WinJS and jQuery. I would prefer just ONE Framework for every task and I prefer jQuery. You can call jQuery functions from WinJS and vice versa because the base is JS. Dosen't have anybody wrapped both together to make use of the WinJS functions in the easy jQuery context? E.g.: see this [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465354.aspx) for flyouts in WinJS. This is the way I would like to use it: $("#buyButton").click(function() { $("#confirmFlyout").showFlyout(); });